# Jquery Confirmation Dialogue - Yii framework

Tags: jquery, dialog, yii

I am trying to use Jquery Dialog box in place of Java script standard confirmation dialog box for my project

I googled and found below nice Jquery confirmation dialogues

http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

I am currently using Yii framework

I am having rows of data with delete option for each row . Clicking on the delete link asks for the confirmation and based on user input it deletes the row .

For that I am using below Java script code. It is Working perfect and no issues

```
"onclick"=>"if (
            !confirm('Are you sure?\\r\\nYou are going to unregister for this subject.')
              ) {     return      }
```

But now to use the above Jquery dialog I don't find a way to implement exactly like above .
Below is the code I tried

```
"onclick"=>"if (
            !jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', 
                 function(r) {
                               return r ; 
                              }
                      )
                ){    return     } "
```

But this didn't help and I even tried some other possibilities too .. But none of them helped . Could some one provide the correct way to handle the above case .

Or if there are other dialog boxes that helps me for my case ..

Thank You

Regards

Kiran

**Full code where I am calling this**

```
    echo (
            CHtml::ajaxLink(
                   'Delete',
                    Yii::app()->createUrl("editcourses/removeCourse"),
                    array(
                            "type"=>"POST",
                            "data"=>array(
                                    "place_type"=>$courses[$i]['course_type'],
                                    "place_id"=>$course[$i]['course_code'],
                            ),
                            "success"=>'js:function(data){  }',
                    ),
                    array(
                            "onclick"=>"
                                if (!jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
                                    return r ; })){return} "
                    )
            )
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer and here it is

```
    CHtml::ajaxLink(Delete,'','',
array( "onclick"=>"                                         
    var parObj=$(this).parent().parent();
    if (!jConfirm('Are you sure?\\r\\nYou are going to unregister for this course.', 'Confirmation', function(result)                    {                                                if(result){                                               
    jQuery.ajax(
        {'type':'POST',
        'data':{'place_type':parObj.attr('place_type'),'place_id':parObj.attr('place_id')},
        'url':'index.php?r=editProfile/removeCourse',
        'cache':false,
        'success':function(data){ 
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $('tr[place_id=\"' + obj.place_id + '\"][place_type=\"' + obj.place_type + '\"]').remove();
        }
        }); 
    }
    })){return }

        "
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you won't be able to implement it exactly the same as the default confirm dialog because the return doesn't happen until the user clicks, at which point the return from the overall function has already happened.

```
"onclick"=>"jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', 
                 function(r) {
                       alert('Confirm equaled ' + r + ': Do Something Here');
                       // deleteRecord(5); 
                              }
                      ); return false;"
```

Comment: Kevin :- Thank You For your response , But my case is I am calling it in Ajaxlink , It calls the action and removes from the database . I provided additional code where I am using . Thank You

Comment: You can't use it the way you were using it. You simply cannot. It will not work. It is not possible. It would require you stopping all scripts on the page from processing, which would prevent the click event on the dialog button from doing anything. I would suggest simply using the default built-in confirm() dialog that comes with the browser.

Comment: Thank You Kevin for your quick response . Then I live with this or change my design .. Thanks again

Comment: I wasn't trying to sound rude, It's just that, it simply isn't possible without using callback methods. You would have to trigger a secondary event or method that actually does the work. I'm not familiar with Yii so it would be difficult for me to suggest a workaround.

Comment: no you are not rude :) :) I spent around 6 hours to find out possibilities :( :(

Comment: Kevin , Finally I am to get the answer . I posted the question in yii forums and one of them responded with idea .